# Why is this cause RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Why is this cause RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded?

```
const myData = ref({
  labels: [] as string[],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [] as number[]
    }
  ]
});


const handleCurrency = (origin) => {
  origin.forEach(item => {
    myData.value.labels.push(item.item); // labels: ['USD'] is ok.
    myData.value.datasets[0].data.push(item.percent); // this line cause error
  });
};

handleCurrency([{item: 'USD', percent: 1, value: 50}]);
```

in my expect, number 1 will put on myData.datasets[0].data => [1].

Comment: can't see how the code would run at all, since an `object` does not have a `.forEach` method - my guess is that your *actual* code is not like this at all

Comment: my mistake, the parameter "origin" is an array

Comment: yes, and as shown now, the code works 100% as you expect

Comment: hmmmm...seems the problem is from the other code...

Comment: this error is almost always due to recursivly called functions, renders causing themselves to rerender etc. try console.logging in different parts of the component-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any errors with your code. The problem is somewhere else.

Check the playground.

```js
const { ref, createApp } = Vue;

const myData = ref({
  labels: [],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: []
    }
  ]
});


const handleCurrency = (origin) => {
  origin.forEach(item => {
    myData.value.labels.push(item.item); // labels: ['USD'] is ok.
    myData.value.datasets[0].data.push(item.percent); // this line cause error
  });
};

const app = createApp({
  productionTip: false,
  data() {
    return {
      myData: myData
    }
  },
  methods: {
   click() {
     handleCurrency([{item: 'USD', percent: 1, value: 50}]);  
   }
  }
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <button @click="click()">handleCurrency</button>
   <pre>{{myData}}</pre>
   
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```